# Replacing multiple empty spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var firefoxIngs = myText.replace(/ /g,"&nbsp;");
```

This is my string:

```
"h  a"//it has two empty spaces between h and a
```

After the code it becomes:

```
"h&nbsp;a"//it has one empty spaces between h and a
```

I want it to be

```
"h&nbsp;&nbsp;a"
```

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: @RenjithKN You cans ee now, I fixed it.

Comment: Are there tab instead of white space? Then, use `\s`. `var firefoxIngs = "h a".replace(/\s/g,"&nbsp;");`

Comment: How about examine the ascii code of your myText: `console.log(myText.charCodeAt(1));`

Comment: @GrantKiely But it also replaces y newlines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works as expected

```
console.log("h  a".replace(/ /g,"&nbsp;"));
```

On the string, you might be missing one space.

### Result:

```
h&nbsp;&nbsp;a
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/kMerT/)**

Comment: But this replaces the new lines too.

Answer (score 0):

This works also

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function validate(){
  str=document.getElementById("input").value;

str= str.replace(/\s/g, '  ');
console.log(str);
}
</script>
    <input id="input" type="text"/>
<input type="button" onclick="validate()" />
```